# Split column and values into multiple rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

Suppose I have a table like this:

| subject | flag | first_date | last_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| this is a test | 2 | 1/1/2016 | 1/4/2016 |

into something like this:

| subject | flag | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| this is a test | .5 | 1/1/2016 |
| this is a test | .5 | 1/2/2016 |
| this is a test | .5 | 1/3/2016 |
| this is a test | .5 | 1/4/2016 |

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Usually I would tend to do this sort of thing in a scripting language. There may be a way to hack it in SQL but likely it won't be pretty. Is there a reason why it needs to be done in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to produce list of consecutive days between `first_date` and `last_date`:

```
with dates as (
    select d::date, last_date- first_date+ 1 ct
    from test, generate_series(first_date, last_date, '1d'::interval) d
    )
select subject, flag/ ct flag, d date
from dates
cross join test;

    subject     |          flag          |    date    
----------------+------------------------+------------
 this is a test | 0.50000000000000000000 | 2016-01-01
 this is a test | 0.50000000000000000000 | 2016-01-02
 this is a test | 0.50000000000000000000 | 2016-01-03
 this is a test | 0.50000000000000000000 | 2016-01-04
(4 rows)
```